# Creating new Model entry using json (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my rails application I am trying to create a new user from a json client.  However, I am a little stuck on what to  send as the json body. The request is properly getting sent to the correct controller, however I keep getting my validations error back as a response.  It says the email and username cant be blank. Am I doing someting wrong?

I am POSTing to this url *localhost:3000/users.json*

I am trying to send this as the json request:

```
{
 "user":
  {
   "email": "foo@foo.com",
   "username": "noob1",
  }
}
```

In my create action i have this:

```
 # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here are my routes:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: updated question with routes.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: my model is the same. with attr accessible on email and username

Comment: now its posting but it makes everything null and doesnt take my inputs for email and username

Comment: Have you tried it without using the Advanced REST chrome extension? Perhaps that is the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using to send the POST? make sure that you have the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`.

Also, try POSTing to `localhost:3000/users.json`.

Comment: i am using Advanced Rest Client chrome extension. Woops I am posting to that usrl. typo.